# How do I get sum of another table's column using group by

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables T1 & T2 and two same columns in both tables C1 & C2. I want the sum of a column T2.C2 using group by clause.

My query is

```
Select T1.C1,
       Sum(T2.C2) 
from T1 inner Join T2 on T1.C1=T2.C1 
group by T1.C1
```

Output is

T1.C1 T2.C2
Name  100
200

I need the sum 300 in front of name

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you. What does "not showing correct" mean? What isn't correct about the results?

Comment: Help yourself and everyone that must read your code. Stop cramming everything together - make your code readable. And obviously you copied an incomplete snippet of code from your app - make an effort and remove the extra closing parenthesis and the "con" variable. And if your code doesn't work, then time to break your logic into pieces you can debug. Pick a set of values for <C3, C1> and select the rows from both tables without joining. Compute the sums manually and evaluate your code strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the braces, quotes and what "con" is.
Try running it this way.

```
Select T1.C1
      ,(sum(T1.C2) - sum(T2.C2)) as remained
from T1 
join T2 s2 on T1.C3 = T2.C3
group by T1.C1
```

Result:

[image]

(Don't mind the row data. I joined the same table and subtracted the same column so all remainders are 0)

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it isn't working for me

Comment: You're using SQL Server? What is the result when you press "execute"?